# CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage from uint8_t buffer

Tags: ios5, ffmpeg, render, opengl-es-2.0, video-processing

I'm developing an video player for iPhone. I'm using ffmpeg libraries to decode frames of video and I'm using opengl 2.0 to render the frames to the screen.

But my render method is very slowly.

A user told me:
iOS 5 includes a new way to do this fast. The trick is to use AVFoundation and link a Core Video pixel buffer directly to an OpenGL texture.

My problem now is that my video player send to render method a uint8_t* type that I use then with glTexSubImage2D.

But if I want to use CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage I need a CVImageBufferRef with the frame.

The question is: How I can create CVImageBufferRef from uint8_t buffer?

This is my render method:

```
- (void) render: (uint8_t*) buffer
```

{
    NSLog(@"render");

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebuffer);
glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// OpenGL loads textures lazily so accessing the buffer is deferred until draw; notify
// the movie player that we're done with the texture after glDrawArrays.         
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, mFrameW, mFrameH, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, buffer);   

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

[moviePlayerDelegate bufferDone];

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

}

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do something similar.
Apparently, you need to create CVPixelBufferRef, and substitute it for CVImageBufferRef. I.e., you first create CVPixelBufferRef, as described at [here](http://allmybrain.com/2011/12/08/rendering-to-a-texture-with-ios-5-texture-cache-api/) (for download), and then get access to pixel buffer:

```
 CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(renderTarget, 0);
 _rawBytesForImage = (GLubyte *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(renderTarget);
```

(Code not mine).

Answer (score 0):

For an actual working example that shows how video data can be passed directly to an OpenGL view see my [blog post](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post12_opengl_write_texture_cache/index.html) on the subject. The problem with looking at a series of "code pieces" around online is that you will not find actual complete working examples for iOS.